# How Do I Get Rid of the Extra White Space at the Bottom of My Nav Bar?

Tags: html

I've figured out how to center my nav bar and get it to stick to the top of the screen...
But for some reason when I got it to stick to the top of the screen it adds this random white space...
Is there a way I can remove it?
 mineflow.us
Thanks.

Comment: Which white space are you exactly talking about?

Comment: Picture and code would be useful.

Comment: Are you referring to the gap between the top of your content and your top nav bar, that shows the background image? You have a Flash `<object>` (which doesn't seem to have any visible content) buried inside your nav bar that has a `height="300"` attribute, which leads to that large gap. Somehow, the parent `div.holder` gets an inline style of `height: 300px`, which contributes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just set this in your css:

```
body {
     padding:0 !important;
     margin:0 !important;
     }
```

Comment: I added the CSS to my code...
I didn't affect anything and the white space was still there.

Answer (score 0):

use any of these methods.

```
   *{
     padding: 0 !important;
     margin: 0 !important;
     }

   your div{ clear:both;}
```

Comment: can you send us the code or put your code on jsfiddle and send the link to check it in a better way. it will be great pleasure to help you